# What's the best way to test WCF services?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've used this tool that microsoft ships with visual studio because it's quick and dirty

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx

But it's kinda clunky and hard to work with.  Are there any other useful test clients out there that you use and don't require creating a new visual studio project and compiling code?

EDIT: I'm looking more for a graphical test tool that I can use to do quick ad-hoc tests of systems in our different environments without having to write a bunch different tests.

Answer (score 18):

[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is another web service testing tool. I strongly recommend it.

Comment: I'm looking for more than just web services, we're using a lot of net.tcp bindings in WCF

Comment: Just add an additional basicHttpBinding endpoint to your service and feed it to SoapUI.

Comment: that wouldn't be testing the netTcpBindings we have which is the whole purpose

Comment: use WCFStorm (http://www.wcfstorm.com) It was made for testing WCF services and can handle netTcpBindings with ease.

Comment: Don't the http bindings provide the same data and interface and the TCP bindings? If so, why do the TCP bindings need to be tested separately?

Comment: In my experience SoapUI was terribly tedious to set up and keep the tests updated. We ended up in writing our own "test framework" in C#. This also had the advantage of better refactoring options when things changed. As it's been a couple of years since then things might have changed though.

Answer (score 8):

You're not going to find any better tool for creating automated tests of WCF servcies than to use your favorite unit test framework and write tests. The test client, nor soapUI will create a test that can run in a Continuous Integration scenario.

Comment: @John, I am using SoapUI in continuous integration builds every day: http://www.soapui.org/userguide/commandline/functional.html

Comment: Thanks for posting that. If you use jUnit to test WCF services, then you should blog that somewhere. Most people would not use Java to test .NET code.

Comment: I didn't mention I use JUnit. With SoapUI you can write web tests and define expectations. These tests can be run on the command line and the results will be written to a standard text file which can be interpreted during the build.

Comment: I followed the URL you posted, and it looked like it created jUnit tests. Again, I would love to see an article or blog post on this. I recommend soapUI for "playing around" with services; I'd be glad to recommend it for testing, if I saw how that could be done.

Comment: I have to agree with Darin -- SoapUI has a command-line runner, and there's absolutely nothing that would prevent its use in a CI environment.

Comment: be more specific.  I've seen people use a Unit Test framework but still create client proxies to test with instead of using mocks.

Comment: also you need to have a UI to enable people like QA to make example requests in addition to TDD tests or integration tests

Comment: I have typically not had QA test web services, as they are more of an internal implementation detail.

Answer (score 5):

[WCFStorm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/) is useful to test the way you're describing.

Answer (score 2):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wcftoolsteamblog/archive/2010/01/04/tips-for-launching-wcf-test-client.aspx

Here are some tips for testing different wcf scenarios.

[image]

Comment: Added some more detail about debugging

Answer (score 1):

Well I end up writing unit tests in MS test. Before each test the service is hosted by the test assembly, and ripped down afterwards. Sure it's not unit testing, so purists will shudder, but it does mean I can run tests as often as I like.

Comment: Together with conventional "service unit tests" that call the service interfaces directly, mocking out the domain tier, we also have "service self-host tests" that host the service in the unit test framework but which also mock out the domain tier. These are kind of a mix between integration tests and unit tests - but they prove our marshalling and serialization is working properly, something otherwise tricky to pull off.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't mean to imply that soapUI does not work for a WCF service exposed using basicHttpBinding.  Using basicHttpBinding would work because the service would be functioning as a legaxy ASMX web service.  However, if one is to switch the binding (or use multiple bindings) to netTcpBinding for example, i dont think it would still be possible to invoke the methods of that service using soapUI. The scenario I'm describing is quite common wherein you have a WCF service exposed on the web using basicHttpBinding endpoint for maximum interoperability, and another endpoint as netTcpBinding(for max performance) used only internally.

Answer (score 1):

There is this new test client called SOA Cleaner, I recommend you try it. It supports WCF. can be found at: http://xyrow.com.

Comment: It's a .NET application. It's very simple and light wighted; deosn't need any installation.

Answer (score 1):

I ran WcfStorm with it's 15 day eval and I'm impressed with it.  Connect to the service and all methods are exposed.  Click a method and you can build multiple test cases.  After you are done you can save these tests (gonna keep mine as a solution file with the service) and as you make changes you can run all tests which satisfies continuous testing.  It also has a command line which should allow you to integrate into your build machine for true continuous testing.

It also supports IronPython so you may be able to script removal of records your test added if you are good with that scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test the client logic:
You can use mocking/Isolation framework to stub the actual calls to the server and use a unit testing framework to write proper Unit Tests.

Testing the server logic can be even easier - all you need is to test the call to the business logic and stub calls to external components (i.e. database).

There is no actual benefit of unit testing the full interaction between the client to the server because you know that WCF works instead add integration testing of the entire environment on a dedicated server/clients.

Comment: There is benefit in a TDD environment, and you're changing your bindings

Comment: so there's testing client logic (proxy) and testing the service itself, the methods which call business layer methods right?  so you really need 2 sets and kids of tests here for a service.

Answer (score 0):

Amazing WCFStorm, but I think is too expensive for an independent developer.

As Darin said, I also recommend soapUI.

But there's a special case, that soapUI doesn't suuport JSON request when you use REST in WCF and send the request as a POST message.

In that case, you can use a tool I found here:

[WCF RESTful JSON automated testing](http://jordi-montana.blogspot.com.es/2012/03/testing-wcf-restful-services-with-post.html)

Comment: Could you be more specific what the special case is?