# How can I actually unit test wcf service by hitting the end point

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing

I am trying to implement integration test for wcf  service by actually hitting the end points getting the data and validating it. I cannot use Dependency Injection as the code is legacy. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620333/whats-the-best-way-to-test-wcf-services

Comment: @JeremyThompson Unit testing and testing are very different things

Comment: @Mick the tools have command line..

Answer (score 1):

You can create an integration test by creating a test project (in the same solution or not) that adds a service reference to your WCF service and executes methods on that service client generated from WCF.

Just to clarify terminology, an integration test is exercising multiple units in a system and verifying their interaction.  This is typically done end to end, meaning it would run the whole WCF service as it would execute on a deployed server.

You mentioned not being able to use dependency injection, but that concern would typically only apply if you were trying to perform a unit test.

Doing endpoint level unit testing of WCF is tough, and I don't know that there's a well understood method to unit test the network level of the service.

You can unit test the service class with dependency injection and then write tests that assert about the correct attributes being applied to the class (via reflection), but many would question the value of that since you would probably test this service in a lower environment prior to deploying to production.

Comment: Is the service going to run automatically Or I have to run it manually everytime I Test.

Comment: If you deploy to local IIS and intend to do a true end to end integration test, the service would already be running since it is IIS hosted

Answer (score 0):

When I had a WCF service to test I broke down the unit testing into serialization and service tests.  A large amount of the issues you encounter in WCF are related to serialization failing.  This can be tested separately and quite simply:-

1. Instantiate a DataContract
2. Populate it with test data
3. Serialize the data contract
4. Deserialize the data contract
5. Compare the object created in step 4 with the object from step 2.

Another set of tests would unit test the business layer independently.

Lastly to test the end to end operation of the service, many would probably criticize the approach I used, but I found it to be effective, my tests would cross correlate service calls, comparing the results to ensure consistency. e.g. A test might create a record, make a call to fetch the record created and make assertions, update the record, fetch the record again and make assertions, delete the record, attempt to fetch the record again to assert it is deleted. The tests would simply use a normal wcf client proxy.

I realise there are many types of services and you may have something a little more complex than a simple CRUD application, but there's usually a way to create a unit tests that cross check each other.