# Unit/Automated test for WCF service configuration

Tags: c#, windows, unit-testing, wcf, namespaces

I have a WCF service that I would like to test in an automated way. A very basic test setup something like

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService)))
        {
            var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50505/myservice");
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new BasicHttpBinding(), baseAddress);

            host.Open();

            using (var client = new MyServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress)))
            {
                var request = new MySoapRequest();
                client.PostSoapRequest(request);
            }
            
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I keep receiving the following error

```
System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException occurred
HTTP could not register URL http://+:50505/myservice/.
Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).
```

Which describes that I must execute a particular command to enable namespace reservations on a per-user basis

> **Configuring Namespace Reservations**
>
> Namespace reservation assigns the rights for a portion of the HTTP URL namespace to a particular group of users. A reservation gives those users the right to create services that listen on that portion of the namespace. Reservations are URL prefixes, meaning that the reservation covers all sub-paths of the reservation path. Namespace reservations permit two ways to use wildcards. The HTTP Server API documentation describes the order of resolution between namespace claims that involve wildcards.
>
> A running application can create a similar request to add namespace registrations. Registrations and reservations compete for portions of the namespace. A reservation may have precedence over a registration according to the order of resolution given in the order of resolution between namespace claims that involve wildcards. In this case, the reservation blocks the running application from receiving requests.

And then further down

> **Running Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7**
>
> If you are running on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7, use the Netsh.exe tool. The following shows an example of using this command.
>
> `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user`
>
> This command adds an URL reservation for the specified URL namespace for the DOMAIN\user account. For more information on using the netsh command type `netsh HTTP add urlacl` in a command-prompt and press enter.

However, because these tests are going to be running in an enterprise-ish environment, I can't just go around willynilly changing ACL rules, or executing arbitrary commands with `netsh`; additionally, there would be multiple developers and testers and build server agents running these commands, so it wouldn't be very maintainable to ask each person, and all new people coming onto the team to do this.

I understand that it is possible to test the business logic very easily; however, the end goal (in my particular case) is to have a test that validates that the service will only function when provided with a specific client certificate, which equates to an automated configuration test. One that tests when the correct client certificate is provided, and one that uses an invalid certificate.

Is automated WCF Service network/configuration testing possible or viable?

Comment: Did you see this question? ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620333/whats-the-best-way-to-test-wcf-services )